# why aren't gems that are fetched from github stored in vendor/cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

All gems that are fetched form the specified source (e.g. source 'https://rubygems.org') are stored in vendor/cache but none of the ones that are fetched from github are (e.g. gem "delocalize", git: "git@github.com:Svensklanemarknad/delocalize.git").

I'd like to include all gems in the vendor/cache because of deploy performance and so that I could only update a specific gem in the vendor/cache to save time on the 'bundle update '.

why aren't gems that are fetched from github stored in vendor/cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `bundler package`.

http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html.

There is an open issue about bundle package not working with git sources, stay up to date here: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/67. I read that there is some not merged patch for bundler which makes the trick.

Comment: it's `bundle package`, and i had to do `bundle package --all` to get the command to take care of caching gems from git sources. See here: http://bundler.io/bundle_package.html